# Cannot install mapping for python 2 (ERROR: No matching distribution found for oldest-supported-numpy)

Tags: python-2.7, installation, pip

I have a strange problem, being unable to install Mapping library for python 2 via pip. Have the following error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/pavloh/miniconda3/envs/deezer2/bin/python2.7 /home/pavloh/miniconda3/envs/deezer2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-eWQJap/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- wheel setuptools oldest-supported-numpy
       cwd: None
  Complete output (7 lines):
  DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
  Collecting wheel
    Using cached wheel-0.37.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
  Collecting setuptools
    Using cached setuptools-44.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (583 kB)
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement oldest-supported-numpy (from versions: none)
  ERROR: No matching distribution found for oldest-supported-numpy
```

The numpy in installed in the environment:

```
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                 conda_forge    conda-forge
_openmp_mutex             4.5                       2_gnu    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2022.9.24            ha878542_0    conda-forge
certifi                   2019.11.28       py27h8c360ce_1    conda-forge
httplib2                  0.20.4                   pypi_0    pypi
ld_impl_linux-64          2.36.1               hea4e1c9_2    conda-forge
libffi                    3.2.1             he1b5a44_1007    conda-forge
libgcc-ng                 12.1.0              h8d9b700_16    conda-forge
libgomp                   12.1.0              h8d9b700_16    conda-forge
libsqlite                 3.39.4               h753d276_0    conda-forge
libstdcxx-ng              12.1.0              ha89aaad_16    conda-forge
libzlib                   1.2.12               h166bdaf_4    conda-forge
ncurses                   6.3                  h27087fc_1    conda-forge
openssl                   3.0.5                h166bdaf_2    conda-forge
pip                       20.1.1             pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
pyparsing                 2.4.7                    pypi_0    pypi
python                    2.7.18               h02575d3_0
python_abi                2.7                    1_cp27mu    conda-forge
readline                  8.1.2                h0f457ee_0    conda-forge
setuptools                44.0.0                   py27_0    conda-forge
sqlite                    3.39.4               h4ff8645_0    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.12               h27826a3_0    conda-forge
wheel                     0.37.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.12               h166bdaf_4    conda-forge
```

Can someone advise on an issue?

Answer (score 0):

`oldest-supported-numpy` doesn't work with Python 2.7. Even the oldest [release 0.1 (Nov 26, 2019)](https://pypi.org/project/oldest-supported-numpy/0.1/) requires Python >= 3.5.

But Mapping doesn't depend on `oldest-supported-numpy`, it [requires](https://github.com/matthewgilbert/mapping/blob/24ea21acfe37a0ee273f63a273b5d24ea405e70d/setup.py#L39) just `numpy`. Perhaps `oldest-supported-numpy` is in your `requirements.txt`? Remove it or replace with just `numpy`.